# Is there any built in browser support for crypto random numbers in IE and Webkit? Firefox has window.crypto

Tags: javascript, cryptography

Is there anything similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript_crypto for IE or webkit browsers?

I just need to generate cryptographically secure pseudo-random numbers, but I don't want to have to include a large 3rd party js library.

Comment: Doesn't that link say that the random function is not implemented?

Comment: @Greg - hmm, guess you're right, didn't read that far down.

Comment: By now `crypto.getRandomValues` is implemented in Firefox and Chrome. In Opera you can use `Math.random`, since they use a secure rng for it. With IE or older browsers things get ugly.

Comment: For current support http://caniuse.com/#search=crypto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly small SHA1 module that could be seeded with Date.now + some salt n pepper to provide a fairly random string.  Strip out the alphas and keep calling until you have enough numbers for your needs.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html

Definitely hacky - so perhaps an ajax call to a webservice would suffice?

Comment: This is definitely also not cryptographically secure!

Answer (score 1):

you should read into a buffer instead a directly into a string, as the above code will be UTF-8 encoded (why you have so many \0xFFFD bytes)

Answer (score 0):

I second the webservice idea and offer this suggestion: [random.org](http://www.random.org/clients/http/), a truly random numbers generator.

Comment: Truly random they may be, but using a webservice is inherently not secure.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed "crypto" in the Firefox 3 global scope, then found [this reference](http://www.coursevector.com/dommanual/dom/objects/Crypto.html).

Unfortunately, when I try `crypto.random(8)` in the JavaScript Error Console, it throws a `NotImplemented` error.  I'd like to see this function made standard.

On node.js running on osx/linux I recommend this:

```
node> var urandom = fs.openSync('/dev/urandom', 'r');

node> fs.readSync(urandom, 8);

[ '.\ufffd\u000f\ufffdK!L\ufffd', 8 ]
```

I believe a synchronous read is ok, because `/dev/urandom` will always be non-blocking and doesn't rely on disk IO.

Comment: If you're working with Node.js, look at the `crypto.randomBytes` function, which provides a buffer of cryptographically secure pseudo-random bytes.

For a random integer, try `crypto.randomBytes(32).readInt32BE(0)`