# Generating unique short IDs - MongoDB to manage collisions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am evaluating the following code to generate a short ID in my Node server (inspired by previous post: [Short user-freiendly ID for mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354581/short-user-friendly-id-for-mongo) ):

```
> b = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(6)
<SlowBuffer d3 9a 19 fe 08 e2>
> rid = b.readUInt32BE(0)*65536 + b.readUInt16BE(4)
232658814503138
> rid.toString(36).substr(0,8).toUpperCase()
'2AGXZF2Z'
```

This may not guarantee uniqueness, but my requirements are to have a short ID of maximum length 8 characters and it must also be all upper case. The purpose of this is to make the ID user friendly.

To ensure that there are no collisions, I am planning to create a collection in MongoDB that contains documents that map the short ID, which will be an indexed field, onto the MongoDB ObjectID of the actual document I want the short ID to refer to.

What is the best strategy for doing this to ensure scalability and performance in a concurrent environment where multiple process on multiple physical servers will be checking for short ID uniqueness?

Comment: Why not use `rid` as your document's `_id` property? That doesn't _have_ to be an `ObjectId`. MongoDB has a [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on `_id` so you'll get an error when trying to insert a document with an `_id` that already exists (so you can generate a new id and re-insert it).

Comment: I need to maintain the ObjectID for reasons that are outside the scope of the discussion here, but lets just assume that I can't change that. What would you suggest in that case?

Comment: I would probably add the `rid` as a property to the documents themselves (not through a "junction collection") and have a unique index on it to make sure you get an error when trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks - would this be suitable for a sharded mongoDB where multiple processes are inserting documents at the same time?

Comment: If you're using sharding (which isn't necessarily required to create a concurrent environment, so I didn't take it into consideration), see [this document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enforce-unique-keys-for-sharded-collections/). It may be difficult to ensure uniqueness across shards.