# Writing Lucky Sevens, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, probability

I'm writing Lucky Sevens and I'm getting mostly expected results based on how dice games work IRL. But every once in a while I get a crazy result.

Specifically I am getting a situation where I will go up 100+ dollars, with hundreds of total rolls but it tells me the rolls at my moneyMax is 2 or something impossible like that.

Is this the small probability of random number generators or do I have something wrong?

Here's the Js:

```
    function rollDice() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }

    function playGame() {
      var startingBet = document.forms["luckySevens"]["startingBet"].value;
      var gameMoney = startingBet;
      var die1;
      var die2;
      var diceSum;
      var rollsNumber = 0;
      var moneyMax = 0;
      var rollsAtMax = 0;

      if (startingBet <= 0) {
      alert("Starting bet must be greater than zero!");
      return false;
      } //end of alert if loop

      while (gameMoney > 0) {
       die1 = rollDice();
       die2 = rollDice();
       diceSum = die1 + die2;
       rollsNumber++;
       if (diceSum != 7) {
        gameMoney = gameMoney - 1;
       } else {
        if (diceSum == 7) {
         gameMoney = gameMoney + 4;
         if (gameMoney > moneyMax) {
           moneyMax = gameMoney;
          rollsAtMax = rollsNumber;
          }
         }
        }
       }
       document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("playButton").innerText = "Play Again!";
       document.getElementById("betStart").innerText = startingBet;
       document.getElementById("rollsNumber").innerText = rollsNumber;
       document.getElementById("moneyMax").innerText = moneyMax;
       document.getElementById("rollsAtMax").innerText = rollsAtMax;
       return false;
       }//end of playGame()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you doubt the randomness of `Math.random()`?
An alternative for Math.random has been ask before on SO.  For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12673691/4003419)

But you could also simply double the randomization to make it even more random.

**For example:**

```js
function rollDice() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.pow(10,14)*Math.random()*Math.random())%6)+1;
}

function rollDices(rolls){
   let roll = 0;
   let eyes = 0;
   let dice = 0;
   let interval = 0;
   eyesCount = {1:0, 2:0, 3: 0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0} 
   while (roll < rolls){
    roll++;
    eyes = rollDice();
    eyesCount[eyes]++;
   }
   return {rolls: roll, eyesCount : eyesCount}
  }
  
console.log(rollDices(1000000));
```

And have a look at the results of this snippet.
It calculates the longest interval that the same eyes are rolled for 2 dices.

```js
function rollDice() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.pow(10,14)*Math.random()*Math.random())%6)+1;
}

function rollOdds(rolls){
   let roll = 0;
   let eyes = 0;
   let dice1 = 0;
   let dice2 = 0;
   let interval = 0;
   eyesCount = {2:0, 3: 0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0}
   eyesPrevRoll = {2:0, 3: 0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0}
   eyesMaxInterval = {2:0, 3: 0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0, 10:0, 11:0, 12:0}
   
   while (roll < rolls){
    roll++;
    dice1 = rollDice();
    dice2 = rollDice();
    eyes = dice1 + dice2;
    eyesCount[eyes]++;
    interval = roll - eyesPrevRoll[eyes];
    if(interval > eyesMaxInterval[eyes]){
     eyesMaxInterval[eyes] = interval;
    }
    eyesPrevRoll[eyes] = roll;
   }
   return {rolls: roll, eyesCount : eyesCount, eyesMaxInterval: eyesMaxInterval}
  }
  
console.log(rollOdds(100000))
```

It shows that it could happen that a seven isn't rolled within 50+ rolls.

But still, a max amount of 2 with a startbet of 100 would mean that a seven wasn't rolled for 98 times.
So yeah, that makes one wonder about the true randomness of `Math.random()`.

A test snippet based on your code:

```js
function rollDice() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.pow(10,14)*Math.random()*Math.random())%6)+1;
}

function playGame(startingBet) {
      
      let gameMoney = startingBet;
      let die1;
      let die2;
      let diceSum;
      let rollsNumber = 0;
      let moneyMax = 0;
      let rollsAtMax = 0;
      let moneyAt7 = 4;
      let roll = 0;
      let rollLimit = startingBet * 10;

      while (gameMoney > 0 && roll < rollLimit) {
       roll++;
       die1 = rollDice();
       die2 = rollDice();
       diceSum = die1 + die2;
       rollsNumber++;
       if (diceSum !== 7) {
        gameMoney = gameMoney - 1;
       } else {
        if (diceSum === 7) {
         
         gameMoney = gameMoney + moneyAt7;
         
         if (gameMoney > moneyMax) {
           moneyMax = gameMoney;
          rollsAtMax = rollsNumber;
          }
         }
        }
       }
    return { 
      startingBet : startingBet,
      gameMoney : gameMoney,
      moneyMax : moneyMax,
      rollsNumber : rollsNumber,
      rollsAtMax : rollsAtMax
    }; 
  
}

// TEST 
console.log(playGame(10000));
```

Remark, it's interesting to notice that with a reward of 4 for seven, that the maximum amount is often achieved under 100 rolls.

To be more fair, the win reward for seven should be at least 5 times the loss amount.

Which kinda signifies that one should quit this game when ahead.  Because it can only gets worse.